# Unable to import plugin to scala project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-plugin, spark-packages

I added this to `<my_project_name>/project/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "bintray-spark-packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"

addSbtPlugin("org.spark-packages" % "sbt-spark-package" % "0.2.6")
```

in order to import [sbt-spark-packages](https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package), but sbt tell me "Extracting structure failed: Build status: Error".

I tried with other plugin but the behavior is always the same.

sbt version: 1.8.2

scala version: 2.13.10

Answer (score 3):

See the ticket

*dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven is forbidden* https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package/issues/50

> Bintray has been sunset.
>
> Bintray is deprecated.

https://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/sbt-spark-package

> This package doesn't have any releases published in the Spark Packages repo, or with maven coordinates supplied. You may have to build this package from source, or it may simply be a script.

Do

```
git clone https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package.git
cd sbt-spark-package
git reset --hard v0.2.6
sbt package
```

Now you can find a JAR at `sbt-spark-package/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/sbt-spark-package-0.2.6.jar`.

Do `sbt publishLocal` and it will be published at `~/.ivy2/local/org.spark-packages/sbt-spark-package/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.2.6/jars/sbt-spark-package.jar`.

Now you can use this sbt plugin in your project:

*build.sbt*

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "scalademo",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
  )
```

*project/build.properties*

```
sbt.version = 0.13.18
```

*project/plugins.sbt*

```
addSbtPlugin("org.spark-packages" % "sbt-spark-package" % "0.2.6")
```

Please notice that `sbt-spark-package` is a plugin to sbt 0.13.x, not sbt 1.x

*Support SBT 1.x* https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package/issues/40

In order to use the plugin with sbt 1.8.2 and Scala 2.13.10 you'll have to upgrade it yourself.

Moreover, `sbt-spark-package` seems to be outdated, abandoned, deprecated

*java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sbt.UpdateConfiguration.copy$default$1()Lscala/Option* https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package/issues/51

*Is this plugin deprecated?* https://github.com/databricks/sbt-spark-package/issues/48

Comment: Done, but there is always the error "Extracting structure failed: Build status: Error"

Comment: @AT181903 Did you do `sbt publishLocal` (for `sbt-spark-package`, not for your project)? Can you see the JAR at `~/.ivy2/local/org.spark-packages/sbt-spark-package/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.2.6/jars/sbt-spark-package.jar`? If you still experience issues please show your full `build.sbt`, `project/build.properties`, `project/plugins.sbt` etc. and full sbt output. Why do you need `sbt-spark-package`? It's outdated.

Comment: I needed it in order to use this: https://github.com/saurfang/spark-knn
But now I tried to import all the code in my project and it works correctly. I didn't use sbt-spark-package